# When does this matrix have zero, one and infinite solution?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

So I've forgotten what the conditions for when a matrix has zero, one and infinitely many solutions. Starting with this matrix:
$$
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
  2 & -1 & -5 & 3\\
  -1 & 2 & a^2+3a & -3a
 \end{array}\right]
\end{align}
$$

I reduced this to:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & a^2+3a-4 & -3a+3
 \end{array}\right]
$$
But I'm not sure when this would have zero, one, or infinitely solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^2 + 3a - 4 = 0$ and $-3a +3 =0$ then you will have infinitely many solutions.

If $a^2 + 3a - 4 = 0$ and $-3a+3\neq 0$, then you will not have any solutions. The point is that a row $(0\quad 0\quad 0\quad 1)$ will correspond to the equation $0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = 1$.

If $a^2 + 3a - 4 \neq 0$ then you will have exactly one solution.

Comment: @rewritten Sorry, I got this answer too quickly and in the 14 minutes I had to wait to accept it I got carried away . . .

Comment: Can you please explain the first scenario why does a matrice have an infinite amount of solution if the last cell is zero and the result iz zero?

Comment: Is it because the x=0, y=0 and z can be anything which and the result on the right can also be anything? example: 7=7, 8=8 45=45 ...

Comment: @wesewx: I am not sure I understand. Please start a new question about this.