# When does a system of equations have infinite, unique and no solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Can someone please tell me what a matrix looks like when there is infinite solutions, unique solution and no solutions. I have been searching the internet and I cannot find a straightforward answer of what the matrix should look like. The question I am faced with is that I have a variable in a 3x3 matrix and I have to get the values of that variable when there is no solution, infinite and unique solution.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995259/when-does-this-matrix-have-zero-one-and-infinite-solution?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390446/solving-a-system-of-linear-equations-k-value-for-infinite-unique-and-no-soluti?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285396/for-which-values-does-the-matrix-system-have-a-unique-solution-infinitely-many?rq=1, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrixII.aspx, http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/s2009/threePossibilitiesRankSymbol-k.pdf

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "look like"?  It may not appear to look like anything unless you are good at doing arithmetic in your head and get used to seeing common factors just by looking. That's not really something that is fool proof or consistant or even well defined. As to *when* matrices have zero, infinite, unique solution, well, I'm sure you googled what linear dependence and independence meant.

Comment: To your mind does the matrix [1,2,3][2,3,5][3,5,7] "look" different than [1,2,3][2,3,5][3,5,8]?  The first one the rows are independent and thus any equations using it will have one unique solution.  The second [1,2,3]+[2,3,5] = [3,5,8] so they are dependent.  If the sums of row 1 and row 2 add to the sum of row 3 there will be infinite solutions.  If not there will be zero solutions.  But as to being able to determine that by "looking" at them.  Well, if you could "see" [1,2,3] + [2,3,5] = [3,5,8] you ... could see it.  If you couldn't see it, well, than you couldn't.

Comment: "what the matrix should look like": unless the system is very simple or you have bionic eyes, you can't tell at a glance. It is a matter of matrix rank.

Comment: I am guessing the OP means a general form. I.E. a matrix with all $0$'s in the last row has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the simpler case of a system of $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns.

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\x-y=1\end{cases}$$ has a unique solution because it is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\2x=4\end{cases}$$ by adding the first equation to the second. Then $x$ is uniquely determined and so is $y$.

Now,

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\x+y=1\end{cases}$$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\0=-2\end{cases}$$ by subtracting the first from the second, and this system has no solution, as the second equation is impossible.

And finally

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\x+y=3\end{cases}$$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}x+y=3\\0=0\end{cases}$$ which has an infinity of solutions as the second equation is always true.

---

The approach generalizes to larger systems. If, by clever combinations of the equations, you obtain always-false or always-true equations, then the system is impossible or indeterminate, respectively.

There is a systematic method to combine the equations in a way that progressively forms smaller systems, called Gaussian elimination. It will transform a square system in a triangular one. If at some stage all remaining coefficients are zero, then you are in one of these singular cases.